# How to get the array of data in a single array?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

```
Array ( [0] => 1,2,1,23,5,2 [1] => 1,1,1,2,3,2 [2] => 2,3,4,2 )
```

So I have this array. I want the all data in a single array like this.How to achieve this.

```
Array ( [0] => 1,2,1,23,5,2,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,3,4,2)
```

Comment: can you add correct tags regarding the language in question?

Answer (score 1):

Merge array in Codeigniter and PHP

```
$multiArr = Array ( 0 =>  Array (1,2,1,23,5,2),
                    1 =>  Array (1,1,1,2,3,2),
                    2 =>  Array (2,3,4,2)
                  );
//-method merge 1-//
foreach($multiArr as $val)
{
   foreach($val as $val2)
   {
      $result[]=$val2;
   }
}
//-method merge 2-//
//$result = array_merge($multiArr[0], $multiArr[1], $multiArr[2]);

foreach($result as $val)
{
    echo $val.", ";
}
```

result:
1, 2, 1, 23, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2,

Answer (score 0):

Array ( [0] => 1,2,1,23,5,2 [1] => 1,1,1,2,3,2 [2] => 2,3,4,2 )

merged = array merge((spread-operator)array);